# Instantiate newRequestQueue Volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have a new class where I try to Instantiate a new newRequestQueue with the with the Volley.

I try to Instantiate It like this:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

And have an error:,

```
newRequestQueue (android.content.Context) in Volley cannot be applied to (pawel.cooker.API)
```

Here's code of my class:

```
package pawel.cooker;

import com.android.volley.*;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class API {

    protected String ServerURL;
    protected String GET;
    protected String POST;
    RequestQueue queue =  Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    public API(){
        setServerURL("http://localhost:63424");
        setGET("http://localhost:63424");
        setPOST("http://localhost:63424");

    }

    //Logowanie
    public boolean CheckLogin (String Login, String Password){
        setGET(getGET()+"/api/user");

        if (){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    }

    public String getServerURL() {
        return ServerURL;
    }

    public void setServerURL(String ServerURL) {
        ServerURL = ServerURL;
    }

    public String getGET() {
        return GET;
    }

    public void setGET(String GET) {
        this.GET = GET;
    }

    public String getPOST() {
        return POST;
    }

    public void setPOST(String POST) {
        this.POST = POST;
    }

}
```

I was also trying this solution:

```
 Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

But still have same problem. How can I instantiate it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey I find solution.

First

1. Add 'extends Application' in class
2. Then queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

Answer (score 1):

I think you have 2 problems here.

1. You are passing in (this) which you can't do at that point.  (this) hasn't been created yet because the constructor hasn't been called yet.
2. (this) is of type API which is the wrong type to pass in. You need to pass in the type android.content.Context